# Someone who is the life of a party

Tags: phrase-request

Suppose in a party you have someone who count on him as the life of the party (someone who knows how to jazz up the party). How can you describe such a guy in to someone else e.g. at that party and how would you fill in the following blank:

> - He is a good...

My second question is that if the following sentence sound idiomatic and natural to you:

> - He knows well how to jazz up a party.

Answer (score 2):

I think you already have it. For me the most natural thing is to say - "he's always the life of the party."

"Jazz up" is not a very common expression. "Spice up" is slightly more common, but I would say - "he knows how to get a party started/going".